# Google sheet delete row after <x> minutes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I need a Google script that automatically removes rows that are older than  minutes.

Each row has a time stamp in column A e.g. 2/25/2015 13:37:00

Comment: I need a Google script that automatically removes rows that are older than X minutes.

Each row has a time stamp in column A e.g. 2/25/2015 13:37:00

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this functionality using Time-driven Triggers. You can set the trigger to be executed every certain amount of minutes.

Here you can find the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable